# Boost : pyconfig.h not found

Tags: linux, python

I am setting up boost-python for the python bindings of a library. Previously, boost was installed but linked against python2.7. After some tribulations, everything from the previous boost install is gone and I am trying to install a fresh boost.

I am using Linux Mint for the record, and Anaconda with python 3.6.8.
It works correctly in the CLI : python --version gives 3.6.8

I then begin to follow the instructions for building boost : https://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_69_0.html

What I got from other threads is to do this :

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

I am not sure I am supposed to since I have anaconda3 but anyway, I did it.

```
./bootstrap.sh
```

here the file project-config.jam is created and the line about python says :

```
using python : 3.6 : /home/myUser/anaconda3 ;
```

I then proceed to build with b2 :

```
sudo ./b2 --with-python -j8 install
```

the installation fails with literally a wall of text full of these :

```
./boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp:50:11: fatal error: 
pyconfig.h: No such file or directory
# include <pyconfig.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

When I search inside ~/anaconda3/include/python3.6m the file pyconfig.h sits there as expected

Is there additional information I should give to b2 or bootstrap ?

EDIT : 
first line given by ./b2 is :

```
warning: failed to open log file bin.v2/config.log for writing
```

after a few lines of checks :

```
config-cache.write bin.v2/project-cache.jam
/bin/sh: 2: cannot create bin.v2/project-cache.jam: Permission denied
...failed config-cache.write bin.v2/project-cache.jam...
...failed updating 1 target.
```

Comment: Most likely, you need to verify the values of `PYTHONPATH` and `PYTHONHOME`.
Also, try to run the build without `sudo`, since Anaconda is installed within your HOME user directory. So fix permission of the build dir pointing to your user, then try without `sudo`.

Comment: PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME were empty and now set to anaconda/lib and anaconda/ directories. I still have the same problem : pyconfig.h not found. I noticed an additionnal problem, I edited the first message

Answer (score 1):

I followed the instruction given by [vmf91](https://www.iditect.com/how-to/55028128.html). Briefly, you type:

```
python --version
pythonX.Y-config --includes --libs
```

X.Y are the major and minor version that you get from the first command. You pick the first element returned by the second command and include it the following command.

```
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH="$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH:/the/previous/path/without/the/I"
```

Then you run b2 again. Et voilà!
For me it worked on a CentOS cluster where i don't own any privilege.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `b2` like this:

```
./b2 cxxflags="`python3-config --includes`" linkflags="`python3-config --libs`"
```